# How to print first or second word in a string with awk?

Tags: awk

So I have a string which consists of two words, where I want to print the two words separately in awk (actually gawk).The string may look like this,

```
str="ab cd"
```

So I have searched the web and all I come up with is examples how to parse this from a file. However, this does not work in my case. It would be quite easy to do in perl; Something like this,

```
my $str="ab cd";
$str =~/(.+)\s(.+)/;
print "$1 and $2\n";
```

However, awk does not have this grouping. The problem is that I need to preserve the input, so `split()`, `sub()`, ... will not help. It would probaby work with `match()`, but this is not so pretty.

Anyone that sits with a better idea?

```
Sample input: str="ab cd"
Sample output: "ab and cd"
```

Note that the "and" is not a part of the matching, but it should be possible to print that string.

BR
Patrik

Comment: Could you please post sample of expected output in your post and  let us know then.

Comment: If you simply want to print it(not sure if I get it correctly). Try like `echo "$str" | awk '{print $1,$2}'` Or if you want to pass shell variable to `awk` as a variable then try `awk -v str="$str" 'BEGIN{split(str,array," ");print array[1],array[2]}` in 2nd solution you need NOT to mention any Input_file since I have only used `BEGIN` section here, let me know?

Comment: Can you explain why split and match are insufficient?

Comment: If you have only one string, no need of awk : str="ab cd"; printf '%s and %s\n' $str. If it's a file, you must tell more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idk what you mean by any of `However, awk does not have this grouping. The problem is that I need to preserve the input, so split(), sub(), ... will not help. It would probaby work with match(), but this is not so pretty.`

The gawk equivalent of the perl code in your question:

```
my $str="ab cd";
$str =~/(.+)\s(.+)/;
print "$1 and $2\n";
```

line for line, would be:

```
str="ab cd"
match(str,/(.+)\s(.+)/,a)
print a[1], "and", a[2]
```

e.g.:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    str="ab cd"
    match(str,/(.+)\s(.+)/,a)
    print a[1], "and", a[2]
}'
ab and cd
```

I don't know if that's the best way to do whatever it is you're really trying to do though since I don't know what it is you're really trying to do!

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v str="ab cd" 'BEGIN{print gensub(/(.+)\s(.+)/, "\\1 and \\2\n", 1, str)}'
ab and cd
```

Change to `-v str="$var"` if you want transfer a variable value to `awk`.

Comment: This looks as if it works. I actually have two different strings (same format) and want to generate a string that looks something like "$1: $2_1, $2_2" where $2_ is pseudo code for first and second string. Anyway this is possible to accomplish with some minor modification( `gensub(/(.+)\s(.+)\s(.+)\s(.+)/, "\\1: \\2 -> \\4", 1, str" "str2)` ). Seriously, this must be the quickest answer I have got ever. Thanks!

Comment: @patrik Fyi: Awk's regex is not as powerful as perl's, it's a superset of ERE. [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

gnu awk, use the 3-argument form of the `match()` function

```
awk -v str="foo bar" 'BEGIN {
    if (match(str, /^(.+)[[:space:]]+(.+)/, m)) {
        print m[1], "and", m[2]
    }
}'
```

```
foo and bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Split string with a white space to an array:

```
awk -v string="ab cd" 'BEGIN{split(string,array," "); print array[1],"and",array[2]}'
```

Output:

```
ab and cd
```

Comment: `split` third argument is not necessary here.

Comment: @karakfa could you explain that? In my case the original string must be preserved. That might be possible with your solution as well, so it would be nice to se for future reference

Comment: split won't harm the original string, but here my note is the default delimiter doesn't need to be specified as the third argument.